# Two fluid columns on the sides and width:auto for the middle column

Tags: html, css, menu, fluid-layout

I need to create a CSS/HTML navigation menu with a logo aligned in the center and menu options on the sides. I thought of doing it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/d32an55L/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">aaaa</div>
    <div id="center"> Center content</div>
    <div id="right">aaaa</div>
</div>

#wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper > div{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
#left {
    background-color:pink;
    text-align:right;
}
#center {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
}
#right {
    background-color:red;
}
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to make the width of the middle column to fit the content inside the column, something like width:auto;

Do you guys know if that can be done? Is there maybe a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

**Edit**:
All I need is to make the middle column wide as the content it contains while the side columns remain fluid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  `width: auto;` will resize the column to a ratio of the content compared to the rest of the page if the content doesn't fill at least one line of space, side-to-side.  When it comes to side navigations, you usually just set a fixed width to those side bars.

Comment: Ok I just need the width of the middle column to be as wide as the content it contains and both side columns to be fluid. Does this clarify what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you note clarifying the intention, there's only 2 ways (that I can think of at this moment) to do this. If you need to maintain reverse compatibility, you'll need to use JavaScript.  Should you only be concerned about the more modern browsers, CSS3 has a property and `display` mode called `flex`.  It's very easy to use.  Here's the modified CSS to implement it:

```
#wrapper {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper > div {
    height:100%;
}

#left {
    background-color:pink;
    text-align:right;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

#center {
    background-color:green;
    flex:0 1 auto;
}

#right {
    background-color:red;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwj7132y/

If you need compatibility for older browsers, I can draw something up.

Comment: That is it! However I am just a bit concerned about browser compatibility. Is there a browser compatibilty non-javascript way to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: @human Sorry for the slow reply, work. ^^'  With the additional displays, you'll get backwards compatibility for IE10 and some of the other major browsers, but I don't know of any solution to what you're looking for, outside of Flash, other than JavaScript. Basically, you'd have to render the content of that column, determine the amount of space it requires, then re-render the entire page using that value as a fixed width.  That's doable only with a client-side script.